# Returning response data from HttpSession post

Tags: swift, httpsession

I created an external HttpPOST.swift file for handling http requests easy. It works great, but when i try to pass the response data to a dictionary, i get an error:

```swift
Cannot assign value of type 'Response' to type '[String : Any]'
```

Can you tell me why? Thanks!

**HttpPOST.swift**

```swift
import UIKit
public var asd = Dictionary<String, Any>()
func apiCall(){
    
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.71:3000/user/login")else{
        return
    }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    // method, body, headers
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let body: [String: AnyHashable] = [
        "username": "Alms",
        "password": "asd"
    ]
    request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: .fragmentsAllowed)
    
    // make rqs
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){ data, response, error in
        guard let data = data,error == nil else {
            return
        }
        
        do {
            let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
            asd = response;
            print("SUCCESS: \(response)")
        }
        
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
        
    }
    
    task.resume()
}

struct Response: Codable {
    var usernameError: String?;
    var passwordError: String?;
    var logOk: Bool?;
    var token: String?;
}
```

Comment: Because you decoded it to Response, you can use JSON serialization instead but Response is much better in terms of readability and Reusability.

Comment: Okay, then how can i pass the Response back to a view where i launched the function?

Comment: Look into completion handlers or watch “Meet async/await”.

Comment: `asd` must be  `Response`, not `Dictionary<String, Any>`. Please stop using trailing semicolons, this is not Objective-C, and also `fragmentsAllowed`, since Swift 5.1 fragmented types are implicitly supported and a dictionary isn't a fragmented type anyway.

Comment: Thank you! Works with completion handler!

Comment: Post your corrected code as an answer so others who encounter your question can see the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected code:

```
import UIKit
func apiCall(url: String, body: Dictionary<String, AnyHashable>, completion: @escaping (Response) -> Void){
    
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.71:3000/user/login")else{
        return
    }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    // method, body, headers
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let body: [String: AnyHashable] = body
    request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: .fragmentsAllowed)
    
    // make rqs
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){ data, response, error in
        guard let data = data,error == nil else {
            return
        }
        
        do {
            let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
            completion(response)
        }
        
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
        
    }
    
    task.resume()
}

struct Response: Codable {
    var usernameError: String?;
    var passwordError: String?;
    var logOk: Bool?;
    var token: String?;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).